# change value of link running php code

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink

i want run a php code when a user click a link  and change temporarily value of link with output returned by script without reloading page and redirect user to another page

for example  if a users click on button :

Click Me!

a code php run for example script.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
    $.get("script.php");
    return false;
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="doSomething();">Click Me!</a>
```

for example if output of script( `$result` ) is: 30

then 30  will  replaces button: "Click Me!" without reloading page

so at the end after the script is executed i have temporarily instead of  "Click Me!" number  30  and if is possible also add a animation gif or something of similar so as: wait wait blinking during execution of script
thanks

Comment: This fiddle will show you how you could update the displayed text in the link: http://jsfiddle.net/vVJLn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, create a class with two methods uW (user wait) uWC (user wait cancel). This class can be reused for future as well

```
var Util = {
uW:function(id) {
            $("#"+id).html("<img src='path to animation GIF' />");        
},
uWC:function(id,data) {
        $("#"+id).html(data) ;        
}
}
```

Now your function will looks like this

```
function doSomething() {
Util.uW('clickme'); // clickme is ID of your anchor tag
$.ajax({
 url: "script.php",
 context: document.body,
  success: function(data ){
    Util.uWC('clickme',data );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for. I am guessing you want to replace Click Me! with the value returned(30). If not, you can user data inside the function to replace whatever u want

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
$el=$(this);
$.get("script.php",function(data){$el.html(data)});
return false;
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(this);">Click Me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="clickme">Click Me!</a>
```

And the javascript code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        $(this).load('script.php');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost have your answers in your question. Use ajax.  http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp  you are also using jquery.  Jquery has excellent documentation on ajax